# Table with a different fonts for different columns

Tags: tables, xetex, fontspec

I'm using XelaTeX to typeset a table with a vocabulary list in a foreign language, with a structure similar to [this one](https://www.tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2005-June/002255.html): different columns are typeset in different fonts (and scripts).
It seems that this should be implemented with `\newcolumntype` from the `array` package.

Below is a MWE of my attempt to typeset one column in Linux Libertine and one in Arial:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}}l}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\fontspec{Arial}}l}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{LA}
Libertine & Arial\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

it defines columns of type `L` (to be typeset in Libertine) and `A` (Arial).

I get the following error message on compilation:
`! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \bool_if:nTF. <inserted text> \par l.16 Libertine & Arial\\`

It seems that the syntax for `\newcolumntype` has changed recently, so based on [the manual](http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf) I tried to define the column as

`\newcolumntype{L}{>{\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}}{l}<{}}`

which results in the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the same error if you try to use `>{\fontspec...}` directly in the tabular. It is not a good idea to set up a font in this place (apart from the error, fontspec would have to do it again in every cell). Setup the fonts first and then use the normal font commands instead:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\testfamily{Cambria}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\rmfamily}l}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\sffamily}l}
\newcolumntype T{>{\testfamily}l}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{LAT}
Libertine & Arial& Cambria\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, so the error notwithstanding, TeX would run out of memory, right? Buty why the error in the first place?

Comment: No, I don't think that TeX would run out of memory. But it is still a waste of time to recreate fonts again and again. `\fontspec` has an optional argument and the code explodes when it is looking if this argument is present. You can avoid the error by using `>{\fontspec{Arial}[]}` or `>{\fontspec{Arial}\relax}` but I don't recommend it.